# WPF Scroll Button (Hold down functionality)

Tags: c#, wpf, button, scroll

I have a listbox of items that I am using, and I have a button I made which scrolls up and down, but the only problem is, that you have to click every single time you want to scroll up and down a bit. I am looking for the functionality to simply hold down on the button and have it scroll.. is this possible in WPF? Perhaps I am overlooking something? I searched the internet and haven't found anything like it. Perhaps someone has done this before?

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try a [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton.aspx). It's what WPF uses for the buttons at the end of scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746649%28VS.85%29.aspx).